# PHP Warnings always display, even with commands to set them to off

Tags: php, warnings

I'm currently having a lot of trouble in implementing some .php files. When I host them on my own server, it all comes out fine, but when I host them on the server where they will be hosted once they are completed, I get a bunch of PHP warnings that look like the below.

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_mysql.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0 
>   Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_mysql.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_mysqli.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0 
>   Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_mysqli.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_soap.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0 
>   Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_soap.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_xsl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0 
>   Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5.6\ext\php_xsl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0

The tricky part is that nothing I'm doing seems to stop these warnings. They show up on any PHP file hosted on the space I have to use, and none of the tricks to hide errors or warnings I have seen are working. So far I have tried:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
@[functionNames]
```

None of which did anything (implmented seperately or together). The warning messages even show in a php file that calls phpinfo() and exits. From my digging online, it seems like the warnings are about a faulty extension path, which can happen sometimes when PHP is updated but the old installation files still point to outdated extensions. I can't be sure that's it though, because I have no way right now of contacting anyone who could be a system administrator or would know anything about the php installation. The php installation seems to be on the C drive of whatever computer the server is on. If I was able to get to that PHP installation I could correct the bad paths, but I don't have access to do that right now.

I believe the reason my error_reporting commands aren't working is because the "Master Value" for each value is set to on. I'm fairly new to PHP though, and haven't used phpinfo() before, so I could very well be wrong. If the normal commands don't work, is there anything that I can do? In case it helps, here's a look at what phpinfo() shows for the errors section: [phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PToD.png)

The warning messages aren't changing the way that any of the code works, it's just really annoying to see them all at the bottom of every single page. PHP is version 5.3.0.

Comment: This errors is php initialization errors, therefore you must set this options in `php.ini`, because `ini_set` work after php is initialized.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't have access to the php.ini file because I can't reach the host computer.